# UIToolbar and UIBarButtonItem behavior on Storyboard, tool bar seems to obscure button items

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uistoryboard, uitoolbar

I think I'm missing something fundamental here. I have a `UIToolBar` with three `UIBarButtonItem`. The view hierarchy appears correct to me, but the bar button items are only visible on the storyboard if they are selected from the hierarchy, and they are not visible at runtime.

`UIToolbar` selected (note you can't see the items):

[image]

`UIBarButtonItem` selected (note the item seems 'greyed out'):

[image]

At runtime the items are not visible (just as they are not visible when Toolbar is selected in the view hierarchy. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

1. Added an image showing the toolbar constraints (Horizontal leading and trailing are both 0).
2. Added an image showing the right UIBarButtonItem selected. Note it has a 'selection box' (which the first UIBarButtonItem does not).

[image]

[image]

Comment: based on what you are showing us, it should work.. So you have to give us a little more information before we can help you find what you are doing wrong

Comment: Hi Heliem, I added some additional information. If I create the buttons programmatically I can get it to work as I would expect, but I'd like to understand what is going on with the Storyboard. Anything else I should look for in terms of more information that would be helpful. This did work previously, I'm not aware of anything that changed. I almost want to 'bring to top' the items.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know what's happening in your specific case.. It is supposed to work like that without any problem. There are a number of things that can be causing this problem. Just from this is really hard to help you, all I can do is guess :S

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issue. The problem turned out to be that I had **Bottom Bar** set to **Translucent Toolbar** in the **Simulated Metrics** panel for the `UIViewController` containing the `UIToolBar`. Setting **Bottom Bar** to **None** solved the problem.

[image: Simulated Metrics setting]

**Simulated Metrics** are a design aid in interface builder, to simulate layout. My guess is that the simulated Toolbar was obscuring the actual `UIToolBar` in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

please change the **tintColor** of your toolbar in interface builder from white to default and it should work.

Comment: Hi suhit, I changed tintColor of toolbar to green (it had been default) and tintColor of item to blue for testing. The toolbar now has a green tint but the items aren't visible (as above). Will edit original post to show constraints.

Comment: check tintColor property of the view and barTintColor property of the toolbar.